# simplicial complex equipped with barycenric metric is complete

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-complexes, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Consider a simplicial complex $C$. On its support $$|C|=\lbrace \alpha = \sum_{v\in C}\alpha_{v}v \mid 0\leq \alpha_{v} \leq 1 , \sum_{v\in C}\alpha_{v} =1\mbox{ and }v|{\alpha_{v}} \neq 0\mbox{ is a simplex in }C \rbrace
$$
 there is a metric, the barycentric metric, defined by $d(\alpha,\beta)=\sqrt{\sum_{v\in C}(\alpha_{v} - \beta_{v})^{2}}$. Is this metric complete ?

Greetings
Ben

Comment: This doesn't look like research level… Please try another forum (e.g. MathStackExchange).

Comment: Benjamin - some extra context might be helpful.  Do you want to place any restrictions on $C$?  Is it finite-dimensional, for instance?

Answer (score 6):

No, this metric need not be complete.  Let $C$ denote the complex with vertex set $\mathbb{N}$, where the simplices are the nonempty finite subsets.  Thus, the points of $|C|$ are sequences of nonnegative real numbers that are eventually zero and sum to one.  Consider the sequences
\begin{align*}
 a_0 &= (1/2,1/2,0,0,0,0,\dotsc) \\\\
 a_1 &= (1/2,1/4,1/4,0,0,0,\dotsc) \\\\
 a_2 &= (1/2,1/4,1/8,1/8,0,0,\dotsc) \\\\
 a_3 &= (1/2,1/4,1/8,1/16,1/16,0,\dotsc)
\end{align*}
and so on.  Then $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence in $|C|$ that does not converge.